# Why Inline asm in C++/CLI creates horrible problem?

Tags: assembly, c++-cli, inline-assembly, mixed-mode

I am using Inline asm in C++/CLI. Horrible problem infact could be a bug I obsereved. 
I passed vector from one function call to another. If I comment the whole code snippet of _asm{....some assembly code here} inside the called function where vector used which are provided to it  from other function, then no problem whole vector gets fine and copied to argument of called function successfully in correct manner.

But If uncmment _asm{} I mean if I use _asm{} patch in called function , it corrupts the whole vectors of objects infact whole object corrupts which contains vectors and other strings data and it just shows for every data inside object like npos=4294967295.

What is it? Why this is so? Is CLI creating problem or I am using inline asm i wrong way?

Kindly help me out , as I am stuck here.

```
             strParamType  = strReturnType;
             if(strParamType.find("IDispatch")!=string::npos)
             {
                 IDispatch* pIDispatch; 
                 _asm
                 {
                   mov  esi,esp 
                       lea  eax,[pIDispatch] 
                   push eax
             }
              }
```

Here If I dont write anything at all inside _asm{} even then problem occurs which I described.

Regards
Usman

Comment: Without any further information, I suppose your asm is wrong. You should post a snippet.

Answer (score 3):

From the source you provide I cannot quite guess what you intend to do, but I'd have a few observations:

1. Especially for using `_asm` in a .NET environment you need to adhere to a set of rules. Refer to, for instance, [Microsoft's advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a8ss06%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
2. Your code doesn't initialize `pIDispatch`. I don't know what follows in your real code, but the assembler code takes the address of the pointer on your stack, and stores it on stack again. That is calling for trouble, unless your code tries to initialize the pointer. But after the if-clause, the pointer will be out of scope!
3. Your assembly code changes the stack pointer without restoring it. This will crash your process, sure thing. Do not do it unless you really know what you're doing (like writing an operating system).